# Why is isomorphism defined as it is in category theory?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question

In terms of an intuitive understanding of categories, I've been told to think of a category as "objects with some structure" and a  morphism as "a transformation preserving the structure". (This understanding obviously falls apart when considering abstract categories, but seems to me to be unrelated to my problem, which is with its interpretation on concrete categories)

An isomorphism is then meant to indicate that the two objects in question have exactly identical structure. It seems to me that we have no guarantee that this notion is captured in general by our general definition of isomorphism.

If you asked someone who only knew of algebraic structures what an isomorphism on concrete categories ought to be, the answer would obviously be "a bijective morphism", but this fails for topological spaces.

By the same token, while it's certainly true that "having a morphism with inverse" ensures that two objects have identical structure for all the concrete categories I can think of, how do we know there isn't some kind of structure that violates our current notion of isomorphism in the same way that topological spaces violate the "naive" algebraic notion?

Comment: How does it fail for topological spaces? In topological spaces, morphisms are continuous functions. Continuous functions with continuous inverses are homeomorphisms...

Comment: That sentence was in reference to the hypothetical "naive" definition of isomorphism which might be given by someone who doesn't know what topology is: a bijective morphism seems to fit the bill for all of the algebraic structures I've seen, but fails spectacularly in this case.

Comment: @poiu45 It sounds like you're supposing that the "naive" person doesn't understand the choice of 'morphism' made in the definition of the category of topological spaces. A morphism in the category of topological spaces is a continuous map, so homeomorphisms fall out of the definition of an isomorphism for free, just as other algebraic notions of isomorphism fall out of the definition when considering the category of groups, or of rings, wherein 'morphisms' are the respective homomorphisms for these spaces. Homeomorphisms are exactly the invertible morphisms in the category of top. spaces

Comment: I hope you were also told that “objects with some structure and transformation respecting the structure” is **not** the intuition you wan to carry forward. Under that understanding, the category of a partially ordered set, for example, would make absolutely no sense. It’s good for *concrete* categories, but not in general.

Comment: Actually, the correct notion of “isomorphism” in the algebraic context **is** “morphism with a morphism inverse”, same as in category theory. This is particularly obvious when you are dealing with partial algebras (algebras with operations that need not be defined on the entire set). The usual way of presenting them as “bijections that are morphisms” is actually a *bad* way of doing it, precisely because it provides the wrong impression (much like defining quotients via normal subgroups/ideals rather than via congruences does).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I understand that this is not the case for non-concrete categories - my question is about the interpretation of this definition specifically for concrete categories.

You say that the correct notion of "isomorphism" is "morphism with morphism inverse" even in algebraic contexts, but I want to know why/if that definition is sufficient in all possible concrete categories. How can we know that our refined definition is not similarly naive?

Comment: @poiu45 "I want to know why/if that definition is sufficient in all possible concrete categories" -- yes! It ends up being exactly what we would want from a definition of 'isomorphism' and nothing more. It's probably an instructive exercise thinking of different examples and convincing yourself that this is the case. It's true for topological spaces as well as all of the common algebraic structures we might study. Another instructive example is the category of small categories.

Comment: Isomorphism is just meant to be a generalisation of "inverse" but for situations where we want the maps and their respective inverses to still respect the structure of the objects in question. It should be clear that "invertible morphism whose inverse is also a morphism" captures this precisely.

Comment: @JackCrawford I understand that it works nicely (ie: actually does indicate morphisms which preserve structure) for all of our examples of concrete categories, but is there any sense in which we can prove this? Given the somewhat fuzzy nature of "having identical structure" as a property, this might not be possible: part of the question is if it is.

Edit: I hadn't heard isomorphism as a generalization of invertible before this point (and our given definition obviously works for that end): is this the general intuition one should hold?

Comment: You can’t prove an intuitive notion. So you can’t “prove” that the definition will always do exactly what you hope it will do. The best you can do is verify that it does exactly what you want in all the instances that you can come up with. So, no, we cannot *prove* that this definition “works nicely”, because there is no precise definition of what “works nicely” means. You can only prove things when you have precise, specific, explicit statements. Unless you have a precise, explicit, clear definition of “works nicely”...

Comment: @poiu45 “is this the general intuition” I believe so; perhaps just because I can’t possibly think of any better intuition. When it comes to “proving” whether it has this property, the first thing you have to do is make the property precise mathematically. When you do that, I think you’ll find that the property *is* the definition

Comment: @JackCrawford I think [this](http://abel.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/preprints/when_is_one.pdf) article kinda sums up the concerns OP has. My professor always said, it is impossible for me to know whether the red I see is the same as the red you see. But, we know that we can set up an isomorphism between our conceptions of the color. That's the best we can hope for.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I suppose the main question was whether or not "identical structure" is a property which can even _be_ formalized, and I suppose the answer is no. Somewhat dissatisfying, but it seems like it's the best one can get.

Comment: @poiu45 Check out my comment above. I think there's something you might appreciate there.

Comment: Well, the best formalization of “identical structure” is “there is a way to get from here to there and a way to get from there to here, the two ways respect structure, and they provide a way to do perfect translation back and forth”... which *is*, **precisely**, “there is a structure-preserving function with a structure-preserving inverse”... i.e., the very definition of isomorphism at issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard way of trying to explain how an isomorphism between two objects of any category means precisely that they look *exactly the same* as far as that category is concerned is via the Yoneda embedding.

In our situation we should observe that two objects $x,y$ in a category $C$ are isomorphic if and only if they represent the same functor, that is, if and only if there is a natural isomorphism between the functors $Hom_C(-,x)$ and $Hom_C(-,y)$. In other words, $x$ and $y$ are isomorphic if and only if they admit isomorphic *sets* of maps from all other objects of $C$. Since a natural isomorphism is merely a natural transformation whose components are bijections of sets, this actually reduces the general notion of isomorphism to the algebraic concept of "bijective morphism", showing that in this sense every category is a category of algebraic structures. In particular, this is not circular-we don't already need to know what an isomorphism is in general to know what a natural isomorphism is!

So, if we define "$x$ and $y$ have precisely the same structure" as "$x$ and $y$ look the same as codomains to all other objects of $C$", formally, $x$ and $y$ represent naturally isomorphic functors, then the conservativity of the Yoneda embedding *proves* that our notion of isomorphism is the correct one.

One possible complaint is that you might wonder why we shouldn't say that $x$ and $y$ are "the same" if they admit the same maps *to* every other object of $C$, rather than from. Luckily, these are equivalent, since objects are isomorphic in $C$ if and only if they are isomorphic in $C^\mathrm{op}$. The main remaining complaint is that we might somehow want *more* of $x$ and $y$ than that the other objects of $C$ see them as being the same. But in that case, it seems clear to me that we're no longer talking about any notion of sameness *in $C$.*

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses (or I hope it does) your concern in the second paragraph, at least for groups. Maybe within category framework this approach becomes "trivial", but I can't say more, as category theory is far beyond my knowledge.

So, a group $G$ shows its structure as soon as we allow the internal operation to fully deploy its effects. Accordingly, we can reasonably state the following:

> **Definition 1**. The *structure* of a group $G$ is the set $\theta_G:=\{\theta_a, a\in G\}\subseteq \operatorname{Sym}(G)$, where $\theta_a$ is the bijection on $G$ defined by: $g\mapsto \theta_a(g):=ag$.

Here a problem arises, if we want to determine whether two groups, $G$ and $\tilde G$, "have the same structure", since in general $\operatorname{Sym}(G)\cap\operatorname{Sym}(\tilde G)=\emptyset$, and then any attempt to "compare by overlapping" the structures $\theta_G$ and $\tilde\theta_\tilde G$ is doomed to fail. We can overcome this issue "by transporting" the structure of $G$ in $\operatorname{Sym}(\tilde G)$, and see whether we can made the "transported $\theta_G$" to overlap with $\tilde\theta_{\tilde G}$. If we succeed, then we can rightly say that $G$ and $\tilde G$ are *isomorphic*, since we have been able to bring the *structure* of one *onto precisely* that of the other. So, with reference to the following diagram:

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\las}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xleftarrow{\ \ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
 &  & \\
G & \ras{\space\space\space f \space\space\space}   &   \tilde G \\
\da{\theta} &  &  \da{\tilde\theta}  \\
\operatorname{Sym}(G) & \ras{\varphi^{(f)}} & \operatorname{Sym}(\tilde G) \\
\end{array}
$$

we set forth this other:

> **Definition 2**. Two groups, $G$ and $\tilde G$, *are isomorphic* if there is a bijection $f\colon G\to \tilde G$ such that the above diagram commutes, namely:
>
> $$\tilde\theta=\varphi^{(f)}\theta f^{-1}\tag 1$$
>
> where $\varphi^{(f)}\colon \operatorname{Sym}(G)\to \operatorname{Sym}(\tilde G)$ is the "structure transporting" bijection defined by $\sigma\mapsto f\sigma f^{-1}$.

Now, as a caracterization of such an "enabling" bijection $f$, the following holds:

> **Claim**. Two groups $G$ and $\tilde G$ are isomorphic (as per Definition 2) if and only if there is a bijection $\psi\colon \tilde G \to G$ such that:
>
> $$\psi(\tilde a\tilde g)=\psi(\tilde a)\psi(\tilde g), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G \tag 2$$

*Proof*.

\begin{alignat}{1}
&\tilde\theta=\varphi^{(f)}\theta f^{-1} &\iff \\
&\tilde\theta_\tilde a(\tilde g)=(\varphi^{(f)}\theta f^{-1})(\tilde a)(\tilde g), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G &\iff \\
&\tilde a\tilde g=(\varphi^{(f)}\theta f^{-1})(\tilde a)(\tilde g), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G &\iff \\
&\tilde a\tilde g=(\varphi^{(f)}(\theta_{f^{-1}(\tilde a)}))(\tilde g), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G &\iff \\
&\tilde a\tilde g=(f\theta_{f^{-1}(\tilde a)}f^{-1})(\tilde g), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G &\iff \\
&\tilde a\tilde g=f(\theta_{f^{-1}(\tilde a)}(f^{-1}(\tilde g)), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G &\iff \\
&\tilde a\tilde g=f(f^{-1}(\tilde a)f^{-1}(\tilde g)), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G &\iff \\
&f^{-1}(\tilde a\tilde g)=f^{-1}(\tilde a)f^{-1}(\tilde g), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G\\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

So, $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$, by setting $\psi:=f^{-1}$, and $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$, by setting $f:=\psi^{-1}$. $\space\space\Box$

Therefore, a bijection between two groups with the property $(2)$ is rightly called *isomorphism*.